# Oracle VirtualBox Lost Data

Tags: intellij-idea, save, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My laptop just shut down when I was compiling my Intellij java project(on my VM Ubuntu guest) and almost all of my files appear now to be 0 bytes (even though I previosly saved them). Unfortunatly I don't have a backup and neither a snapshot of the VM.

Is there any way I can go to a previous configuration of my VM? Or to recover my files...

Answer (score 0):

I used Local History from Intellij and got back my files.